# NaN , Returning in browser

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I get back

> Nan ,

what does this mean?

In the distinctPlayer variable are two values 110 and 115. I want to have for this two Player the name and the sum of Note.

The first query of finalTotal gives for 110 the sum of Note 8 + 2 = 10 and for 115 the sum of Note 4 + 3 = 7 back.

The second query ... name of 110 is Dave and for 115 is Tom.

The while loop have an execution of 2 times. Then I try to safe each line of while in a variable. First line is Dave: 10 and second line is Tom: 7. But I don't get this back. At the moment the result is NaN ,

In the html the function is defined as

```
<p>
  <pre>{{otherHelperFunction}}</pre>
</p>
```

And here is the function

```
var d = 0;

while(distinctPlayer[d]) {
  var finalTotal = Spieltag.find({SpielerID: distinctPlayer[d]}).map(function (doc) {
    total =+ doc.Note;
  });

  var finalName = Spieltag.find({SpielerID: distinctPlayer[d]}).map(function (doc) {
    return doc.Name;
  });

  var finalReturn =+ finalName +" "+ finalTotal;
  d++;
}

return finalReturn;
```

Comment: You're using `=+`, the correct syntax is `+=`, but if you haven't used that variable previously, you should just use `=`. Additionally, `NaN` stands for `Not a Number`.

Comment: See [Global_Objects/NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) for more info on NaN.

Comment: I change =+ to += but now I get back 110,110 ,. I think the problem is how I write finalName and finalTotal into finalReturn. Is it possible to give back more lines/vales regarding to the while clause? In the browser I want to see Dave 10 and Tom 7. Must I use an array to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

NaN means Not a Number. Try the following:

```
var finalReturn = finalName + " " + finalTotal;
```

The addition assignment operator is += which can be used as follows:

```
var a = 1;
a += 1 // a now has a value of 2
```

The += operator in this case represents a = a + 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're using =+, the correct syntax is +=

Answer (score 0):

Let's go,

NaN is Not a Number, you are trying treat as number what not Number.

You are using `=+`, you should use `+=`.

Probabily the `doc.Note` not is number.

JavaScript have function `isNaN`, this return a boolean.